# Front-end design: Dynamically add items to list

Tags: database, web, frontend

So, I've tried several times to thrust myself into the world of website development. Each time, I have abandoned a project for one simple reason: lists.

I would like to know, from front to back, the dataflow for a system which follows the following sequence of events:

1. The user is shown a list in a website
2. The user fills out a new list item in some sort of modal dialog
3. The user hits "Submit" and that item is now added to the list.

   - That new list item is sent to the server to be stored

Would there be a whole new page load? When would the data be posted to the server? What are the various options for this (seemingly simple) application? I am targeting relatively small web tools. Not necessarily single page, but I'm not against it.

I understand how to add the new `<li>` to a list with JQuery, and I know how to build the modal with HTML. I can pull the data from the modal, but I'm not sure how to take that data from JQuery, turn it into the appropriate block of HTML (which could be rather complex), and store the new record in the database.
I can't seem to find a tutorial on this sort of data handling.

Thank you!

Comment: That's a very broad question. There are several dozen technologies you could choose from here. Before this gets shut down due to everyone chirping in on their favorite ones, let me suggest [meteor.js](https://www.meteor.com/). It simplifies what you're aiming to do so much, that you'll be building web apps like that in an hour. Do the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you! I'll be sure to look into meteor.js! While I agree that the question has many different answers, I would argue that it isn't so broad that it should be closed. I just need someone to explain to me the necessary building blocks to investigate. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Since you mentioned jQuery, let's use jQuery. Ready? Here we go!

I'm assuming you have a `textarea` or an `input` in your modal where a user can enter text. If so, give it an `id` attribute so it can be referenced, like `id="myText"`.

Then, to take the `textarea` or `input`'s content and turn it into a list item in your list, you'll need to append an `<li>` with the textarea's content to its parent `<ul>` tag. Again, you'll need some way to reference the `<ul>` tag, so give the `<ul>` tag an `id` attribute, something like `myList`, so it becomes `<ul id="myList">`.

Now, it's just a matter of taking the `val()`ue from the input field, and appending it to the list. This is how you do that.

```js
var textareaStuff = $('#myText').val();
$('#myList').append('<li>'+textareaStuff+'</li>');
```

That wasn't so hard, was it? This is actually quite fun.

I will admit, POSTing stuff to the server may take some getting used to, but it's not too hard.

I've prepared an HTML file for you that does all these things, with pretty detailed documentation. It should be able to help you learn what you're wanting to learn. It's below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My jQuery Experiments</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Here's your list with its ID so we can reference it in JS. -->
  <ul id="myList">
    <li>Sample Item 1</li>
  </ul>
  <input id="myText"> <!-- Here's your input field. This can be in a modal. -->
  <button id="addItemButton">Add Item</button> <!-- We need a save button. -->

  <!-- Include jQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

  <!-- This is the javascript you'll need to write and understand -->
  <script type="text/javascript" >

    // When the element with id="addItemButton" is clicked,
    $('#addItemButton').click(function() {

      // Append the stuff in brackets to the element with id="myList"
      $('#myList').append('<li>' + $('#myText').val() + '</li>');

      // ^ The stuff in brackets is an li code with the value of the HTML
      // element with id="myText", your input field above.

      // Now to post it to a server, we'll need to use AJAX.
      // Luckily, jQuery has an AJAX function. It looks like this:

      $.ajax('http://example.com/mysaver.php', {

        // We're POSTing stuff to the server.
        method: 'post',

        // This is the data to send to the server.
        // It is a JSON object. 
        // If using PHP, you'll get $_POST['item'] = whatever is in id="myText"
        data: { item: $('#myText').val() },

        // If the AJAX request was successful,
        success: function(data) {
          // The argument 'data' contains whatever the server returned. 
        },

        // If not,
        error: function(jqXHR) {
          // Handle your error here.
        }
      });

    });

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this was helpful! Go ahead and approve this answer if it was, and please feel free to ask further questions in the comments and I'll do my best to help out where I can.